# Laravel error: 'Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row' with protected $withCount

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

All of sudden without me making any changes on shared hosting server I started getting 500 error & in the logs I found `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row`. After few debugging I found, this issue came probably because I am trying to get count from 2 different model at once.
I use the following method to get the count.

**Inside my user model:**

```php
protected $withCount=[
    'comments',
];

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\Models\Comment::class,
        \App\Models\Post::class,
        'post_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'comment_id');
}
```

The query this method builds is:

```sql
select `users`.*, 
    (select count(*) from `comments` 
        inner join `posts` on `posts`.`post_id` = `comments`.`comment_id` 
        where `users`.`id` = `posts`.`post_id` 
          and `comments`.`deleted_at` is null  
          and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null) as `comments_count` 
from `users` where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

I tried to comment the code and check it ran fine. I just want the count of comments, but I am not sure if there's something wrong with the method I am trying to get the count from. This was working fine till now but all of sudden I have started getting this error on my shared hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs due to your sub query. In my point of view, you have tables called *comments, users and posts*. And using the subquery you're trying to retrieve comments counts which are associate with each posts.
EX: if you have post as id: 1 then it may have comments ids as :1,2 so the count is 2
but in your case you have multiple posts and multiple comments for those posts.
So your subquery returns multiple counts for those posts
like :
comments count
2 (this may be for post id 1)
3 (this may be for post id 2)
so it provide that error.

As the solution you may do something like below

***If you want to get all the comments***

```
select `users`.*, comments_count.count
from `users` 
left join (select count(*) as count, user_id from `comments` 
          and `comments`.`deleted_at` is null) as `comments_count`
on comments_count.user_id = users.id
where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

***If you want to get comments related to the post***

```
select `users`.*,
comments_count.count,
comments_count.post_id
from `users` 
left join (
      select count(*) as count,
       post_id, 
       comments.user_id as user_id 
      from `comments` 
      inner join `posts` on `posts`.`post_id` = `comments`.`post_id` 
          and `comments`.`deleted_at` is null  
          and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null) as `comments_count` 
ON `users`.`id` = `comments_count`.`user_id` 
where `id` = 1 
and `users`.`deleted_at` is null 
limit 1
```